How to assign grouped orders to a single vehicle in a routing problem with OR-Tools?
I am working on a routing problem using OR-Tools where groups of orders (containers) must be delivered by the same vehicle, but any vehicle can be assigned to the group. The orders within a group cannot be split between vehicles, and the solver should optimize the assignment of groups to vehicles.
Here is what I have tried so far:
I imposed a constraint ensuring that each group is served by at most one vehicle, but the solver couldn't find a solution.
for i in range(self.num_items):
    group = self.items_group[i]
    idx = i+self.num_depots
    group_vehicles[group].append(self.routing.VehicleVar(self.manager.NodeToIndex(idx)))

for v_list in group_vehicles.values():
    used_vehicles = [v for v in v_list if v>-1]
    constraint = len(used_vehicles)==0 or self.routing.solver().Max(used_vehicles)==self.routing.solver().Min(used_vehicles)
    self.routing.solver().Add(constraint>0)

I attempted to add pairwise constraints between orders within the same group to ensure they are served by the same vehicle, but this approach also failed to work.
I am struggling to implement this requirement correctly. Obviously the problem does have a solution and just to be sure I'm working without any other constraint but this. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to model this type of constraint in OR-Tools?
Thanks in advance for your help!

At the start of the solve all nodes are unassigned thus the VehicleVar is equal to -1 (a semaphore value used when unvisited) .
Since solver will try to add node one by one to built its first solution, you constraint must be "all VehicleVar of my group must be -1 or use the same vehicle index value".
note: You could try to also use the ActiveVar(index) which is a boolean set to false if node is not visited aka ActiveVar(index) * VehicleVar(index) is 0 if unvisited or vehicle_index otherwise...

Thank you, Mizux, for the reply. I agree with your analysis, and I believe I’ve already implemented this approach. In fact, if you watch at the code snippet above, my constraint is exactly: “None of the group is delivered, or the maximum vehicle ID delivering at least one must be the same as the minimum vehicle ID delivering at least one.”

Since the solver is adding node one by one there is nearly no chance to move from 0 node visited to all of them in a route in one step...

Right, but I'm not constraining 0 to all, I'm saying that if the node is visited it must be visited from the same vehicle as the other visited nodes in the group, or at least this is what I meant :-)

instead of adding a hard constraint you may first want to try a penalty of
cost += 10000* self.routing.solver().Max(used_vehicles)==self.routing.solver().Min(used_vehicles)
to see if the solver can find a feasible solution, or is there a bug in your program. It sometimes helps to relax the problem to help solver find initial feasible solution which might be difficult to reach in a more constrained original problem.

thx, I've tryied this approach even with a huge penalty, but the fact is that this is really a hard constraint for our use case and I can't accept solutions with mixed vehicles per group.

you can reject solution if the cost of solution is beyond an upper limit and try with different local search strategies and different strategies for initial solution creation in the case where the cost of solution is beyond the upper limit.
